# How can I port OEM specfic app?

Tags: java, android, apk, porting, nexus-5

I have three devices, an LG, Sony and one of which being an HTC and I really like the Music Player and the Camera, but now I wish to port the Music Player to my Nexus 5. I know this isn't something that can be done easily, but I'm pretty good at modding and theming and have had experience in app modding. I have searched everywhere on how I can port OEM specific applications to a specific device, and I found one poost but it wasn't really specific. Thread was on xda by Rizal.

My question is how can I port OEM specific apps, if you know of any method to port applications that'll be great, if you have had experience on porting applications please give me a method and some tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct "method". I've ported some apps and it basically involves the following:

- Install app on device
- It will most likely crash, debug it
- Then decompile the classes.dex to smali files and start msking edits
- Making these edits requires knowledge of Java to retrace the code.

Comment: Thank you, I've gotten 5 applications to work on my N5 they just need some resizing.